# Cron.d file not running

Tags: cron

I am new to Linux and have a problem that I have tried to look online and could not find a solution

I have 4 scripts that are running in cron.d 3 of them I set to run every minute and they are fine and logging into the output files but the last one should run at 1:00 am but it will not.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 390 Jul 29 14:03 Test

* * * * * root /usr/sa/dir1/dir2/script1.sh >> /usr/sa/dir1/logs/fileoutput 2>&1
* * * * * root /usr/sa/dir1/dir2/script2.sh >> /usr/sa/dir1/logs/fileoutput 2>&1
* * * * * root /usr/sa/dir1/dir2/script3.sh >> /usr/sa/dir1/logs/fileoutput 2>&1
0 1 * * * root /usr/sa/dir1/dir2/script4.sh >> /usr/sa/dir1/logs/fileoutput 2>&1
```

I checked the permission and all seems to be fine as the same script from `cron.d`  file are running as I can see entries from `cron` that are executed in `/var/log/messages` and same from the log files.

Things I have tried till now and worked

- IF I vim the file and change for the 4th script to run every minute it runs fine.
- IF I vim the file and change for the 4th script to run during the day it runs.
- IF I include the script under crontab of root user and it runs ok.
- IF I run script form the command line it runs ok.
- I can not figure out why `viming` the file in `cron.d` the script will be executed by `cron`.

Thank you in advance for the help

Things I have tried till now and worked 
IF I vim the file and change for the 4th script to run every minute it runs fine.
IF I vim the file and change for the 4th script to run during the day it runs. 
IF I include the script under crontab of root user and it runs ok.
IF I run script form the command line it runs ok.
I can not figure out why viming the file in cron.d the script will be executed by cron.

I don't see errors in /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

Are you commiting this crontab by just editing the raw file or are you using `crontab <my-new-crontab>`? If you aren't then try the latter. :)

Comment: yeah I am using vim but will try it and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I end it up adding the scripts to the crontab of the user root and seems to be ok.